# Spark parquet file partitioning

Tags: apache-spark-sql, parquet, partition

I have 10000 (each file size is 13kb) parquet files in 30 folders. so totally 13 MB.

The property `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` is set to `128MB`(by default)

But when I try to read the data using Spark, total no of partition is `235`.

Can any one tell me how this is calculated?

Comment: How many cores do you have on your cluster?

Comment: @David Vrba.. 3 datanodes with4 cores each